# Why am I getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'corner'

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6

In the console in chrome, I am getting the error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'corner'**

I am using Drupal 6 and my code looks like this:

```
drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.corner.js');
drupal_add_js("$('.rc-container').corner('4px');$('.dd').corner('tl 0px').corner('4px');$('.n-menu-item').corner('tl 4px').corner('tr 4px');",'inline');
```

Comment: Make sure you're including the accompanying JS

Comment: Because the jQuery plugin `corner()` function isn't known. Check your includes, and please share the generated HTML.

Comment: What is `corner()`? What is the plugin? Can it be chained?

Comment: @BenM - that turned out to be the case. I checked the generated js file (the one that drupal creates) and it didn't include the js corner code, so I looked on the server and the file wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Writing js-code inline like that is bad practice. You should write that in seperate js-files.
Drupal also has a good templating mechanism.

Concerning your question: you should check browser console. There might be an 404 error, showing, that jquery.corner.js is not found. In that case you should rewise path to js-file.